# Is it OK if I use the word 'empathized' in this blank?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, passive-voice, grammaticality-in-context

> Emotions and emotional sensitivity are important to our effectiveness in problem-solving. We would like our actions to be well reasoned and make sense, but each element of a good working relationship depends on emotional input. Our understanding of another person's perceptions and interests will be inadequate unless it is **e_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** -- unless we know, to some degree at least, what it feels like to be in that situation. If we don't understand how others are feeling, our communication may suffer. Only if we recognize how they feel about things will we able to persuade them. Finally, a full acceptance of another person as someone whose interests and views matter depends on our feelings of caring and respect.

May I put `empathized` in the `_`s?

Comment: There's no established use for "empathise" as a transitive verb, so there's no passive available. Where did you find it shown as transitive?

Comment: @BillJ In some Eng-Kor dictionaries..

Comment: *She is being empathized with*?

Comment: @BillJ http://www.ybmallinall.com/styleV2/dicview.asp?kwdseq=138962&kwdseq2=0&DictCategory=DictEng&DictNum=1&ById=1&PageSize=5&StartNum=&GroupMode=&cmd=0&kwd=em·pa·thize

Comment: @JasonBassford I clarified the point not to make it an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Empathize* isn't transitive, so you need a prepositional phrase if you want to express the action as being directed in some way.

*With* is common with *empathize*: *to empathize with X* means to share feelings with X or share the feeling X with somebody.

So one solution is to tack on *with* in that sentence (also you say *those are* because "perceptions and interests" are 2 things):

> Our understanding of another person's perceptions and interests will be inadequate unless *those are* empathized with.

But this sounds weird - because empathy doesn't really "work" as an action without a person either as the subject of *empathize* or the object of *with*.

Use the noun *empathy* instead, which works better.

> Our understanding of another person's perceptions and interests will be inadequate unless *there is empathy*.

Or this:

> Our understanding of another person's perceptions and interests will be inadequate unless we [using *we* because *our*] empathize with that person.

Comment: Actually, the answer provided by the teacher was 'empathetic', modifying 'understanding'. Anyway I appreciate your kind explanation.